# How can i change the 'system_time_zone' variable in mysql server to "UTC+8" in my host machine(windows10 system)

Tags: mysql

the version of mysql server is 8.0.11 and the host machine's operate system is windows10 .I have read the mysql references in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html. And it said that I can set the TZ environment variable to change the system_time_zone variable in mysql server.But after I set the TZ environment variable to "UTC+8" and restart the mysql server.The 'system_time_zone' is 'UTC',which I want it to be 'UTC+8'.How can I make it right?Thank you very much!

Comment: *I set the TZ environment variable to "UTC+8"* This is incorrect setting. You must specify the offset only. `SET SESSION time_zone = '+08:00';`. Or named timezone only (timezones must be loaded into according system tables previously). `SET SESSION time_zone = 'AWST';`.

Comment: I want to let the mysql  server to get the system time of the host machine to set the time zone. @Akina